# Export csv in php like Microsoft excel format

Tags: php

I have trouble with exporting csv in php just like Microsoft excel.
When I Save the exported file as csv in Microsoft excel everything is OK.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and what the actual problem you get is?  (does it fail to download or open the file?)

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it seems like there is issue with headers while saving csv file. Please try below header for same.

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");exit;
```